# Michael Hartl's Ruby on rails Tutorial - Rspec test fail - undefined method `microposts'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

So I'm at [chapter 11](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#top) of Michael Hartl's (great) RoR tutorial.
After finishing chapter 10, i decided i would add the micropost form the a user's profile page, so that you can post from there too, and not just from the home page.

I managed to make it work just fine, but it somehow crashes my test suite...

Here's the error message I get from Rspec, for all of my User_pages_spec.rb Profile page tests:

```
UserPages profile page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit user_path(user) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `microposts' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:17:in `show'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is my test file:

```
  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    let!(:m1) { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Foo") }
    let!(:m2) { FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: user, content: "Bar") }

    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1', text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }

    describe "microposts" do
      it { should have_content(m1.content) }
      it { should have_content(m2.content) }
      it { should have_content(user.microposts.count) }
    end
  end
```

I do have the microposts method in my user model:

```
has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
```

and here is the code I added in the user show view:

```
    <% if current_user?(@user) %>
      <section>
        <%= render 'shared/micropost_form' %>
      </section>
    <% end %>
```

I also added the @microposts variable to the show action in the UserController:

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
end
```

So as everything seems to work out just fine, in development and in production, I don't understand why my tests won't pass... They passed before I added the micropost form in the user profile page...

If anybody can explain what the problem is, I would greatly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your test specs I think you are visiting the user_path but didn't sign in any user. As a consequence current_user is nil during spec execution. You would need something like

```
before do
    sign_in(user)
    visit user_path(user)
end
```

where `sign_in` is a function that resides (in my version of the tutorial) at spec/utilities.rb. It should be there from a few chapters before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know rspec, but the error message is indicating that nil does not have the method microposts, meaning user is returning nil rather than an instance of User.